# Subset data by randomly selecting rows based on two columns

Tags: r, loops, random, unique, subset

I have a large data.frame and I want to create a new data.frame with randomly selected rows based on two columns.

There are 90 unique elkIDs with ~48 rows per FixDate. I would like to make a new data.frame with 90 unique elkIDs with 4 randomly selected rows per each FixDate.

Data looks like this:

```
> head(df)
elkID        X       Y       Fix.Date.Time    FixDate
1   245 550345.1 4826676 2010-02-24 10:00:58 2010-02-24
2   245 550217.9 4826519 2010-02-24 10:30:47 2010-02-24
3   245 550066.3 4826478 2010-02-24 11:00:41 2010-02-24
4   245 549912.6 4826419 2010-02-24 11:30:48 2010-02-24
5   245 549977.3 4826438 2010-02-24 12:00:55 2010-02-24
6   245 549795.1 4826294 2010-02-24 12:30:29 2010-02-24
```

I want it to look like this (4 rows per FixDate for each unique elkID):

```
> df2
elkID        X       Y       Fix.Date.Time    FixDate
1   245 550345.1 4826676 2010-02-24 10:00:58 2010-02-24
2   245 550217.9 4826519 2010-02-24 10:30:47 2010-02-24
3   245 550066.3 4826478 2010-02-24 11:00:41 2010-02-24
4   245 549912.6 4826419 2010-02-24 11:30:48 2010-02-24
5   245 549977.3 4826438 2010-02-24 12:00:55 2010-02-25
6   245 549795.1 4826294 2010-02-24 12:30:29 2010-02-25
```

Using RStudio V0.99.467 & R3.2.1

Comment: I had a similar need once. I wrote a small function to perform this kind of stratification based on columns and values. Maybe it can help you, see `stratified` in the `SciencesPo` package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For large dataframes I recommend the package `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[, .SD[sample(.N, 4)] , by=.(elkID, FixDate)] #or
df[, .SD[sample(.N, 4)] , keyby=.(elkID, FixDate)]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to loop through them you can try the following:

```
# initialize a new dataframe to store new data
newdf = NULL    

# extract unique elk IDs
IDs = unique(df$elkID)

# create a loop to subset each ID first (i loop) and secondly
# loop through the unique dates (j loop)
for(i in 1:length(IDs)){
  data1 = df[df$elkID == IDs[i],]
  dates = unique(data1$FixDate)
  for(j in 1:length(dates)){
    data2 = data1[data1$FixDate == dates[j],]
    # this should select 4 rows at random for each particular ID and date
    data2 = data2[sample(1:nrow(data2),4),]
    newdf = rbind(newdf,data2)
  }
}

head(newdf)
tail(newdf)
```

Does this do what you are looking for?

Comment: The one line of code was so tempting, I went straight to that one. Thanks for the help though! I'll try this one later, since I am really struggling with writing for loops and this one is written for my data!